# How can I vary opacity in a plotly R chart

Tags: r, plotly

Here is an toy example. The opacity value in data.frame has no impact

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(6,3),opacity=c(1,0.2))

plot_ly(df,
    type="bar",
    x=x,
    y=y,
    opacity=opacity,
    marker = list(         
      color='#5a22e3'    
    )
    )
```

I might also want to extend have a color column in df and utilize that in place of the fixed value above
TIA

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add a `group` so that it knows to look for more than one opacity:

```
plot_ly(df,
        type="bar",
        x=x,
        y=y,
        group=x,
        opacity=opacity,
        marker = list(         
          color='#5a22e3'    
        )
)
```

[image]

**Update**

With respect to color, adding `color` as a variable does a similar thing as `group`, but it needs to be a factor or a character variable (note that I removed `group`):

```
plot_ly(df,
        type="bar",
        x=x,
        y=y,
        opacity=opacity,
        color=as.factor(x)
)
```

[image]

Since there are only two levels, this will give you a warning, so you can put all that into a `suppressWarnings()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. And just for information, it is also possible to set color as a variable as well

Comment: As of 2016, the `group` argument in `plot_ly()` is deprecated.