# Vary Opacity in Plotly for R

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to get the opacity of points in a 3D Scatter to change at the point level, so that some points can be solid and others can be invisible.  I can make the whole plot change to a single opacity and I've tried to mimic this earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683630/how-can-i-vary-opacity-in-a-plotly-r-chart).  I can replicate this for the bar charts but not for the scatter.

Test-Data:

```
set.seed(123)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
d$Opacity <- runif(1000,0,1)
```

I have tried two approaches:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, z=depth,
             type="scatter3d", mode="markers",
             opacity = Opacity)

plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, z=depth,
        type="scatter3d", mode="markers",
        markers = list(opacity = Opacity)
)
```

However, both versions of the code give me this:
[image: Output]

Comment: have you tried this (like suggested in the earlier question): plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, z=depth, group=carat,
             type="scatter3d", mode="markers",
             opacity = Opacity, marker = list(         
          color='#5a22e3'    
        ))

Comment: I had not.  It sort of looks like it works, but only a handful of the points look like it worked.  Additionally, the "Update" of the code stated that adding a Color specification should work.  I've tried that and I still can't get it to work (if I can get it to work, I'd ultimately like to have points have different opacity but colored based on some factor so it is realistic to include it).  E.g. plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, z=depth, color=cut, type="scatter3d", mode="markers", opacity = Opacity)

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? Im looking at the same problem at the moment