# Setting conditions for colors in plotly

Tags: r, colors, plotly

I am working on a plot in R using plotly and I would like to turn all the values that are 0 or a particular number let's say 10 to be transparent  while I want others to follow the colorscale.

Here's the line of code that I had been using. I have no clue how to set the condition.

```
plot_ly(Data, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, text = ~label, 
                hoverinfo ="text",
        type = 'scatter3d', 
        mode = 'lines',
        line = list(width = 6, color = ~values, colorscale = 'Viridis'))
```

Would appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, you could make a new variable saying 0.5 for values that you want transparent and 1 for values you don't want to be transparent. Map this new variable to `opacity` (something along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683630/how-can-i-vary-opacity-in-a-plotly-r-chart)).